# Div mouse hover

Tags: javascript

Work on ASP.NET 2.0 C# on the web. In my site, I have three `div`s. Each `div` contain several elements. When I mouse hover a `div` then it expands on vertically, initially, all `div` are in Collapsible. **How to write this mouse hover event.** How to set all `div` content in collapsible. I want **Accordion** but the Accordion header takes place vertically not horizontally.

Comment: Is "Collapsible" some ASP.NET specific terminology?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want an [Accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [jquery Accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion).

To make the sections expand and collapse on mouse over, use this:

```
$('.selector').accordion({ event: 'mouseover' });
```